# Algorithm / Python to parse a log file into its nested start and end pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to facilitate reading a log file.

I've managed to transform each line of the log file so that I have a Python dict with facts about each line, meaning I have the file in memory as an array that looks something like this:

```js
[
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'iwiv', 'linenumber':5},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'83fi', 'linenumber':200},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'28c8', 'linenumber':360},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'28c8', 'linenumber':365},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'28c8', 'linenumber':370},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'28c8', 'linenumber':375},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'aowq', 'linenumber':400},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'pwiv', 'linenumber':520},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'pwiv', 'linenumber':528},
    {'keyword':'d', 'is_pair':False, 'details':'9393', 'linenumber':600},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'viao', 'linenumber':740},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'viao', 'linenumber':741},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'viao', 'linenumber':750},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'viao', 'linenumber':777},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'aowq', 'linenumber':822},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'83fi', 'linenumber':850},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'details':'iwiv', 'linenumber':990},
    {'keyword':'c', 'is_pair':False, 'details':'1212', 'linenumber':997},
]
```

**What I'm trying to do is "pair up"** "nearest neighbors" whose "keyword" matches**, like matching parenthesis nesting, and dump the output as some sort of standardized made-for-nesting-text syntax like XML or JSON.

I do already know which keywords are "made to stand alone" versus "should have a match," as labeled in my input as "is_pair."

I'd like to give some sort of "lines range" for a pair I combine ... for those that are one-liners, I don't care if it's a "start" & "end" pair with the same number in it, a null End, a totally different label *(as in my examples)*, etc.

Here are a few examples of what output *could* look like:

**Example 1**

```xml
<a start="5" end="990">
    iwiv
    <a start="200" end="850">
        83fi
        <a start="360" end="365">
            28c8
        </a>
        <a start="370" end="375">
            28c8
        </a>
        <a start="400" end="822">
            aowq
            <b start="520" end="528">
                pwiv
            </b>
            <d linenumber="600">
                9393
            </d>
            <b start="740" end="741">
                viao
            </b>
            <b start="750" end="777">
                viao
            </b>
        </a>
    </a>
</a>
<c linenumber="997">
    1212
</c>
```

**Example 2**

```xml
<a start="5" end="990" details="iwiv">
    <a start="200" end="850" details="83fi">
        <a start="360" end="365" details="28c8"/>
        <a start="370" end="375" details="28c8"/>
        <a start="400" end="822" details="aowq">
            <b start="520" end="528" details="pwiv"/>
            <d linenumber="600" details="9393"/>
            <b start="740" end="741" details="viao"/>
            <b start="750" end="777" details="viao"/>
        </a>
    </a>
</a>
<c linenumber="997" details="1212"/>
```

**Example 3**

```js
[
    {
        'keyword':'a',
        'start':5,
        'end':990,
        'details':'iwiv', 
        'inner':[
            {
                'keyword':'a',
                'start':200,
                'end':850,
                'details':'83fi',
                'inner':[
                    {'keyword':'a', 'details':'28c8'},
                    {'keyword':'a', 'details':'28c8'},
                    {
                        'keyword':'a',
                        'start':400,
                        'end':822,
                        'details':'aowq',
                        'inner':[
                            {'keyword':'b', 'start':520, 'end':528, 'details':'pwiv'},
                            {'keyword':'d', 'linenumber':600, 'details':'9393'},
                            {'keyword':'b', 'start':740, 'end':741,  'details':'viao'},
                            {'keyword':'b', 'start':750, 'end':777,  'details':'viao'}
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {'keyword':'c', 'linenumber':997, 'details':'1212'}
]
```

I don't necessarily need help with the details of writing JSON or XML files.

**What I'm not sure about an algorithm for, particularly Pythonically, is the "clump-matching" aspect of this work.**

How do I approach transforming something from a "linear list" to a "nest" where every element with an `open` matches the next-nearest `close` of the same keyword that isn't already "claimed" by a better candidate?

Comment: Are you sure that this nests?  That is, can you open A, then open B, then close A and then close B?  (Trivia, this is how you write something that is valid html but not valid xhtml.)   If it does nest, you just have to use a stack of currently open tags.  When you see a close, if it matches the open, you're done.  If it doesn't, the challenge will be in how to best make something nested out of something that is not.

Comment: 1) I'm sure enough to give it a try and find out. 2) Thanks for the HTML trivia; I'd heard as much but hadn't heard an example like that. 3) Thanks for the "stack" suggestion!  You know what's funny?  When I was eyeballing the log file, I held up my hand and kept count of how deep I was in opens & closes by raising and lowering fingers as I muttered, "Okay, one, two...one...two, one, two, one, two, one...zero."  Yet I could not think of that as how to approach the problem with code.  Thank you!  :-)  If you add "with a stack" as an answer, I'll accept it, if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest solving this with a stack.  If the data is nested properly, it will be solved easily.

However I'd put in an explicit error check for improperly nested data.  Because if you're getting the wrong close tag, that is where the hard questions come.

Answer (score 1):

if your data is going to be ordered on line numbers, the best move is to use a stack. It also helps you when you want to put it into the nested format that you need.

By reusing your data, we get:

```
data = \
[
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'iwiv', 'linenumber':5},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'83fi', 'linenumber':200},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'28c8', 'linenumber':360},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'28c8', 'linenumber':365},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'28c8', 'linenumber':370},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'28c8', 'linenumber':375},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'aowq', 'linenumber':400},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'pwiv', 'linenumber':520},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'pwiv', 'linenumber':528},
    {'keyword':'d', 'is_pair':False, 'details':'9393', 'linenumber':600},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'viao', 'linenumber':740},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'viao', 'linenumber':741},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'open', 'details':'viao', 'linenumber':750},
    {'keyword':'b', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'viao', 'linenumber':777},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'aowq', 'linenumber':822},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'83fi', 'linenumber':850},
    {'keyword':'a', 'is_pair':True, 'type':'close', 'details':'iwiv', 'linenumber':990}, # added 'type':'close'
    {'keyword':'c', 'is_pair':False, 'details':'1212', 'linenumber':997},
]
```

Please note that I added a close on the data with line number 990, otherwise there wouldn't be a matching pair. If there is no closing pair, you will loose the first line (you can check at the end if the stack is empty, to catch it).

```
# The level of nesting, since we increase if we find an open
# the first open will get a depth of 0
depth = -1

# We store the complete answers and the stacked answers.
result, stack = [], []


for row in data:
    # Check if the type is open, or if the data is unpaired
    if row.get('type', None) == 'open' or not row['is_pair']:

        # We store it on the stack and increase nesting level
        stack.append(row)
        depth += 1

    # If there is no match, we close it directly.
    # Or if the type is closing
    if not row['is_pair'] or row.get('type', None) == 'close':

        # We get the last item on the stack
        matching_open = stack.pop(-1)

        # We will sort on the linenumbers to make sure that everything will be in order
        # we also store the dept for our layout (we are following example 2)
        result.append((matching_open['linenumber'], depth,
                       f'{" " * 4 * depth}<{row["keyword"]} start="{matching_open["linenumber"]}" '
                       f'end="{row["linenumber"]}" details="{row["details"]}">'))

        # Decrease nesting level
        depth -= 1
```

Basically we will loop through your data and check for a sign that there is an open type. If so we append it to the stack. if we found the matching close we will add it to the found results. For printing it in the correct order and adding the closing parenthesis we also need to know the depth of the nesting. For formatting I added an extra tab (4 spaces) for every added level.

In case there is still something left in the stack, we can check it by using;

```
if stack:
    raise ValueError("There is still a value in the stack, matching is not possible!")
```

Now we still have to output the data in the correct order, since the closing happens in reverse order therefore we sort the result on the linenumbers, which is the first item of the tuple. We check if we changed nested level and if we get more nested we store the keyword. In the case we reduce nesting, we drop the closing signs.

```
# For the closing signs we need to keep track of our depth and opening keyword
temp = []
old_depth = None

# We only need the depth and message, so we discard the linenumber
for _, depth, message in sorted(result, key= lambda x: x[0]):

    # If the old depth was larger, we dropped a depth and we
    # need to put in a closing sign </a>
    if old_depth is not None and old_depth > depth:
        for num in range(old_depth - depth):
            close_open = temp.pop(-1)
            print(f'{" "*4*(old_depth-num -1)}</{close_open}>')

    # If we jump a depth we need to store the closing sign
    if old_depth is not None and old_depth < depth:
        temp.append(message[4*depth + 1])

    # Update the depth and print the message, since we append everything
    old_depth = depth
    print(message)
```

This will result in the following output

```
<a start="5" end="990" details="iwiv">
    <a start="200" end="850" details="83fi">
        <a start="360" end="365" details="28c8">
        <a start="370" end="375" details="28c8">
        <a start="400" end="822" details="aowq">
            <b start="520" end="528" details="pwiv">
            <d start="600" end="600" details="9393">
            <b start="740" end="741" details="viao">
            <b start="750" end="777" details="viao">
        </a> 
    </a>
</a>
<c start="997" end="997" details="1212">
```